Kekaya and Magadha
Kekaya's capital was known as Rājagṛha or Girivraja. Although , in the Critical addition of the Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa , the word Girivraja is used for a city which is different from the Kekaya capital.
My doubt is that in the Mahābhāratam and post-Mahābhārata times , the Capital of the Magadha kingdom was known as Rājagṛha and Girivraja too , so is there any connection or is it just a coincidence?

On what basis did you conclude that Girivraja is the same place as Rājagṛha?

@Bingming , In the Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇam 2.68.21 , The messangers of Ayodhyā are said to have reached "Girivraja" , although this Verse is not present in the Critical Addition. In the Critical the word "Girivraja" , as I've stated in the question occurs only once and that to for a city different from the Kekaya capital. Even in the Vulgate version of the Rāmāyaṇa , the name Girivraja occurs twice , once in 2.68.21 and other in the Bāla Kāṇḍa where it is used for a different city than the Kekaya metropolis.

Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa doesn't mention Rājagṛha as the capital afaik, plus you equated both places, what was the basis of doing so? This question is still not answered.

@Bingming , well Rājagṛha is mentioned as the City where Bharata , Śatrughna , Bharata's uncle Yudhājit and Aśvapati Kaikeya were present. So it might be the capital. So is Girivraja a different city than Rājagṛha?

may I ask, what is the śloka where they are mentioned to be in Rājagṛha?

Anyway, I checked the commentaries on 2.68.21, the comms. Amṛtakataka and Tilaka state that Girivraja is Kekayapura and is also known as Rājagṛha. Other comms. such as Bhūṣaṇa, Tattvadīpikā, Śiromaṇī, etc. state that Girivraja is Kekayapura, but don't mention Rājagṛha.

@Bingming , in 2.70.1-2 , the messangers are said to have met Yudhājit in Rājagṛha.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Bingming , do you know the answer to this question? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/59479/the-word-linga-in-ancient-upanishads
