The word "Linga" in Ancient Upanishads
The Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad mentions the word linga-
तदेष श्लोको भवति । तदेव सक्तः सह कर्मणैति लिङ्गं मनो
यत्र निषक्तमस्य ।

Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad 4.4.6

The Bṛhadāraṇyaka is considered as one of two ancient Upaniṣads , the other being Chhāndogya. The word linga occurs in later ( still ancient ) Upaniṣads like Kaṭha and Muṇḍaka. does this make Bṛhadāraṇyaka a later Upaniṣad? And is the word linga present in other ancient Upaniṣads like Chhāndogya and Taittirīya?.
